# ControlsFx notification adds padding into application

Tags: javafx, controlsfx, tornadofx

[This is the image from my system before call ControlsFx notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiF1a.png)

[This is the image from my system after call ControlsFx notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7lJb.png)

It adds a border in the left, right top and bottom of the screen. I have already searched the documentation but there's nothing talking about the mistake.

This is my code:

```
Notifications.create()
                .title(title)
                .graphic(ImageView(Image("/image/error_icon_little.png")))
                .text(text)
                .position(Pos.TOP_RIGHT)
                .hideAfter(Duration.seconds(4.0))
                .show()
```